# Custom web.config section not saving

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have implemented custom section in web.config and want to save data there, in runtime debug when you check it contains all values that you put there and save without any exception. But web.config file didn't get updated at all.

I have following custom section in web.config

```
 public class PrintersSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("PrintForm", Options = ConfigurationPropertyOptions.IsRequired)]
    public PrintFormElement PrintForm
    {
        get
        {
            return (PrintFormElement)this["PrintForm"];
        }
        set { this["PrintForm"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("Printers", Options = ConfigurationPropertyOptions.IsRequired)]
    public PrintersCollection Printers
    {
        get
        {
            return (PrintersCollection)this["Printers"];
        }
        set { this["Printers"] = value; }
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly()
    {
        return false;
    }
}



public class PrintFormElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("xmlPath")]
    public string XmlPath
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)base["xmlPath"];
        }
        set { base["xmlPath"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("formName")]
    public string FormName
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)base["formName"];
        }
        set { base["formName"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("sdateFormat")]
    public string SDateFormat
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)base["sdateFormat"];
        }
        set { base["sdateFormat"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("createOnTechpadMarkAsComplete")]
    public bool CreateOnTechpadMarkAsComplete
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)base["createOnTechpadMarkAsComplete"];
        }
        set { base["createOnTechpadMarkAsComplete"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("createOnSurveySubmit")]
    public bool CreateOnSurveySubmit
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)base["createOnSurveySubmit"];
        }
        set { base["createOnSurveySubmit"] = value; }
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly()
    {
        return false;
    }
}


 [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(PrinterElement), AddItemName = "printer", CollectionType = ConfigurationElementCollectionType.AddRemoveClearMap)]
public class PrintersCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new PrinterElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        if (element == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("element");

        return ((PrinterElement)element).Location;
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("default", IsRequired = false)]
    public string Default
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)base["default"];
        }
        set { base["default"] = value; }
    }

    public new PrinterElement this[string location]
    {
        get { return base.BaseGet(location) as PrinterElement; }
    }

    public void Add(PrinterElement element)
    {
        base.BaseAdd(element);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        base.BaseClear();
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly()
    {
        return false;
    }
}


public class PrinterElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("location", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
    public string Location
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)base["location"];
        }
        set { base["location"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)base["name"];
        }
        set { base["name"] = value; }
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here how it looks in web.config:

```
<printers>
  <PrintForm xmlPath="H:\Temp\print3.txt" formName="test-form"
    sdateFormat="MM-dd-yyyy" createOnTechpadMarkAsComplete="true"
    createOnSurveySubmit="true" />
  <Printers default="PrinterA">
    <clear />
    <printer location="1" name="PrinterA" />
    <printer location="2" name="PrinterB" />
  </Printers>
</printers>
```

This is how I editing it:

```
 webConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");

            var printXmlConfig = (PrintersSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("printers");

            printXmlConfig.PrintForm.XmlPath = model.PrintXMLPath;
            printXmlConfig.PrintForm.FormName = model.PrintXMLFormName;
            printXmlConfig.Printers.Default = model.PrintXMLPrinterName;
            printXmlConfig.PrintForm.SDateFormat = model.PrintXMLSDateFormat;
            printXmlConfig.PrintForm.CreateOnTechpadMarkAsComplete = model.PrintXMLCreateOnTechpadMarkAsComplete;
            printXmlConfig.PrintForm.CreateOnSurveySubmit = model.PrintXMLCreateOnSurveySubmit;
            printXmlConfig.Printers.Clear();
            model.PrinterPerLocation.ForEach(p => printXmlConfig.Printers.Add(new PrinterElement { Location = p.Key, Name = p.Value}));

            webConfig.Save();
```

But nothing updates in web.config, what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
printXmlConfig.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
```

or

```
webConfig.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
```

before

```
webConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
```

Comment: Already, no effect also tried ```webConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full, true);```

Comment: Have you checked in debugger that the values in printXmlConfig are changed?

Comment: Yes, in debugger they are updating but not in config file, i have tried force save - no success